# Error: Function components cannot have string refs. We recommend using useRef() instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-deployment, ace-editor

Im using ace Editor in my react app and am getting the above error. I want to put the contents of the Ace Editor IDE that im using in my react app from a function call which is triggered through a submit button.

```
<AceEditor
ref='aceEditor'
height='100%'
width='100%'
mode={ideLanguage}
theme={ideTheme}
fontSize={ideFontSize}
showGutter={true}
showPrintMargin={false}/>
```

And this is the button

```
<Button
type='button'
buttonStyle='btn--primary--normal'
buttonSize='btn--medium'
onClick={SendCode}
>SUBMIT</Button>
```

And this is the function

```
const SendCode = () => {
  console.log(this.refs.aceEditor.editor.getValue());
};
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code from where you define the ref/`sendCode` function and render the button? A snippet code would be ideal

Answer (score 18, accepted):

String refs are legacy way to set a DOM reference.

With latest React release, it is advisable to use `React.useRef()` hook for functional components and `React.createRef()` for class components.

You can read more details at -
https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs

And I can guess, you might have turned on the strict mode with `<React.StrictMode>` higher-order component. Thats' why there is an error/warning thrown.

What you should do -

1. Declare a ref variable.

   `const aceEditorRef = useRef();`
2. After that , replace `ref='aceEditor'` with `ref={aceEditorRef}` .

```js
  <AceEditor
    ref={aceEditorRef}
    height='100%'
    width='100%'
    mode={ideLanguage}
    theme={ideTheme}
    fontSize={ideFontSize}
    showGutter={true}
    showPrintMargin={false}/>
```

3. Use aceEditorRef.current to get DOM reference

   ```
   const SendCode = () => {
     console.log(this.aceEditorRef.current.editor.getValue());
   };
   ```

Comment: I am relatively new to React. Can u explain in a simple manner what changes I could do to my code to achieve the desired result. Thanks in advance

Comment: declare a ref variable. `const aceEditorRef = useRef();` After that , replace `ref='aceEditor'` with `ref={aceEditorRef}` . use `aceEditorRef.current`  to get DOM reference.

Comment: @KevinMoeMyintMyat, how can we have access to ```aceEditorRef``` from different component ( sibling component) on the dom?